# HowTo turnoff Apache2 cache on Ubuntu?

Tags: apache-2.2, cache, trac

**Here is my problem:** after default installation of apache2 for Ubuntu it's started to retrieve old pages for [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/), for example, I made a small changes (simply edit page) in trac-wiki section, push "Submit" button, and after the page updated I saw a page with new changes, **but** when I click on "Edit" button again on the same page, it gave me the edit page **without** the last changes (cache gave me back the old page - and I have to press F5 to update the page)...

PS: when I configured HTTPS on my server, the problem for HTTPS content disappeared!

Here is what I'm using:

1. *System*: Linux hostname 2.6.32-24-generic #39-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 28 05:14:15 UTC 2010 x86_64 GNU/Linux
2. [Trac 0.12](http://trac.edgewall.org/)
3. Python 2.6.5
4. Apache 2:

---

```
$ apache2 -V
Server version: Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Apr 13 2010 20:22:19
Server's Module Magic Number: 20051115:23
Server loaded:  APR 1.3.8, APR-Util 1.3.9
Compiled using: APR 1.3.8, APR-Util 1.3.9
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     Worker
  threaded:     yes (fixed thread count)
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APACHE_MPM_DIR="server/mpm/worker"
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=128
 -D HTTPD_ROOT=""
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/lib/apache2/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/var/run/apache2.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="/etc/apache2/mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="/etc/apache2/apache2.conf"
```

Thanks for advice!

PSS: If you need some more outputs of some configures, just comment me, and I append them to my question post!

Comment: Try ctrl+f5 in your browser. Might be the browser that is caching the page and not the webserver.

Comment: @Espennilsen: I have 100% sure, that it's not the browser cache.

Comment: If it's the browser caching, that might be because the server tells it that caching is safe...

Comment: @Jan Claeys Sorry, but I have not got you post... In my case, as I mentioned this is NOT the browser cash... Thanks.

Comment: Does this problem appear on other browsers, on other computers?  Check that first before delving into Apache configuration.

Comment: @Redmumba Yeap, :( Fiirefox, Safari, Opera, IE, - all with the same problems. I tried disable cache (`mod_cache`, `mod_mem_cache`, `mod_disk_cache`, `mod_file_cache`) with `a2dismod` - but still no luck. I this may be I need to upgrade apache version to 2.2.16?!

Comment: Based on several mailing list posts, it sounds like it may be related to mod_python's configuration.  http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracModPython has some specifics on setup; have you followed this through and verified it?

Comment: @Redmumba Thank you guys for your comments, I had figure out what was the problem - it's because corporate proxy caching (f*cking proxy) all content. Web server and browsers are working as expected! Thank you all for your time!

Comment: @Prix Ok, I will do so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**: the problem was in corporate proxy. If I'm using other Internet Providers, the problem disappeared!